# Text has margin but there is no margin given

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to build a newsletter with table (I have to cause some emailclients ignore div boxes etc ).

The problem that I have is that I would like to have the text " Test test " on the same height beginning like the pic left to it. and the blue button should also be on the same height. I made a pic from the Photoshop layout how it should look like and on js fiddle so you see how it is now.

```
<tr style="background-color:#deeef4;">
    <td width="250" cellpadding="0" colspan="2" valign="top" style="padding:15px 25px;">
        <p style="display:inline;color:#00668a;">OBERTAUERN <span style="color:#a9a9a9;font-size:13px">Gültigkeit der Pauschale: 22.03. – 12.04.2014 & 19.04. – 04.05.2014</span>
        </p>
        <br>
        <img src="http://www.awesom-media.de/linie.png">
    </td>
    <tr style="background-color:#deeef4;">
        <td width="300" style="padding:10px 25px;display:inline;">
            <img src="http://www.awesom-media.de/ab1.jpg">
        </td>
        <td width="400" style="text-align:left">
            <p>Test Test</p>
            <ul>
                <li>7 Tage Aufenhthalt inkl. Frühstück</li>
                <li>6-Tages-Skipass für die Skiregion Obertauern</li>
            </ul><a href="#"><img src="http://www.awesom-media.de/button.png" width="345" height="35" border="0"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tr>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sBaNL/)

[image]

Comment: A good start is giving the `<p>Test Test</p>` a `margin:0;` like this `<p style="margin:0;">Test Test</p>`

Comment: With Chrome I see the fiddle the same as the image...

Comment: Is this browser specific, because it looks the same in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

It is due to `p` default `display:block` property which takes some margin by default.

Change it to `display:inline` and you can also remove the `margin-top`

```
p{
  display:inline;
  margin-top : 0px
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sBaNL/3/)

for image button you can add the margin-top `style="margin-top:15px"`

Comment: yeah but the button under the text should be also on the same height with the pic next to it. just like in the preview pic link

Comment: @user3279670 you can add the margin-top with image to see that effect. look at here http://jsfiddle.net/sBaNL/3/

Comment: thx. could ya help me by the last think. i would like to have the sun and..... in one line with the 7 tage .... so that there should be no space just like in the pic. http://jsfiddle.net/sBaNL/6/

Answer (score 0):

I updated your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sBaNL/1/

I did two things:

- Remove the top margin from the `<p>` surrounding `Test Text`
- Make the surrounding `<td>` to vertically align its contents to the top:

.

```
<td width="400" style="text-align:left; vertical-align: top;">
    <p style="margin-top: 0px;">Test Test </p>
    ...
</td>
```

Comment: yeah but the button under the text should be also on the same height with the pic next to it. just like in the preview pic link

Comment: Can't access the pic thanks to a proxy. :(
So I have to guess. :-)
Now I gave the left pic's `<td>` a `rowspan` and split the right `<td>` in two, across two rows: http://jsfiddle.net/sBaNL/4/

Answer (score 0):

To avoid all such uncessary margin, padding etc to all elements, you do the following in the beginning of the css files

*:{margin:0px;padding:0px;...}

This will overright all the browser's default properties.